# Join attribute based on overlapping area and attribute value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, overlapping-features

I want to Join a score attribute from a world boundary(Boundary 2) to another world boundary(Boundary 1) based on the spatial relationship between the two.
Unfortunately they are mostly quite different than one another, For gaps and silvers over the edges I can simply join based on the largest overlap area and assign the attribute value from Boundary 2. However there are cases like below image where there are overlaps in the individual region covering a larger area for which I would like to pick the attribute with the largest value.
[image]

So in the example above the Boundary 2 contains the attribute 'Score' which I would like to join to Boundary 1 but should be Score 600 as it is the largest instead of just the value from the larger area. I was wondering if there is a way to achieve this. I’m using ArcGIS Desktop.

**Progress Update:**

Following the suggestion from FelixIP in the comments, I proceeded with the analysis but considered joining both boundaries and then converting them to points as they are not a perfect overlap of each other, a few countries have additional sub regions in them for Boundary 2 and both the boundaries have slivers around the edges. This solves the problem of assigning the highest score from Boundary 2 for the case above but creates a problem of assigning the highest score in other regions where the boundaries overlap around the edges instead of taking the centroid value as shown in the image below where the score assigned is 60 due to the edge case, while it should have been 2 considering its a score assigned to that region at the center. Any scores around the edges of the boundary is I aim to filter out efficiently(while being aware that it can't be a perfect match, but at least greater than 90% accuracy). I have tried creating a buffer of around 1 and 2kms but either filters out too less or too many.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the "inside center" of each Boundary 2 feature falls in the correct polygon in Boundary 1, the following should work:

1. Run Feature to Point on Boundary 2, with "Inside" selected
2. Run Spatial Join with:

   a. target_feature = Boundary 1

   b. join_feature = Boundary 2 points (from Step 1)

   c. join_operation = JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY

   d. match_option = CONTAINS
3. Dissolve the result of Step 2, using the OBJECTID (and any other Boundary 1 attributes you want to retain) from Boundary 1 as the dissolve field and calculating the maximum score using Statistics Field
   [image: Maximum score]